# Process list of histograms into separate histograms - R

Tags: r, histogram

I have a list of data frames which look like this

**F0001**

```
    PoseID  Score
1   AAAA_1  -13.70
2   AAAA_2  -9.21
3   AAAA_3  -7.60
4   AAAA_4  -6.28
```

**F0002**

```
    PoseID  Score
1   AAAB_1  -14.90
2   AAAB_2  -13.92
3   AAAB_3  -13.49
```

And essentially I'd like to generate plots for each data frame's $Score and spit them out as images.

One of the ways I've tried was to import all the data frames into a list.

```
lst <- mget(ls(pattern='^F\\d+'))
```

then run the `hist()` on each separate data frame in the list and push that out into a list of histograms.

```
hist <- lapply(lst, function(x) hist(x$Score))
```

The idea would then be to spit out that list as separate histograms saved to files. Seems like a simple thing but it's beating me at the moment. Any R boffins have a good way to do this? Maybe other approaches (e.g. for-loop on each separate data frame rather than adding it to a list and performing operations on it)?

Comment: do you want to save hist as an image?

Comment: Yep, that's exactly it.

Answer (score 1):

The following saves each file with the name `image1`, `image2`,... as a pdf file in your working directory. You can also change pdf to jpeg or png or ps.

```
lapply(1:2,function(i){ 
pdf(paste0("image",i,".pdf"))
hist(mtcars[,i])
dev.off()})
```

Comment: "Error in lst[, i] : incorrect number of dimensions"

Each of the data frames added to the list have the same number of columns but vary wildly in number of rows. Do you think that is what's causing this?